# automatic image gallery insert

Tags: php, image, automation

I have this code set up for inserting any image that is uploaded to my "images" folder, right into a  gallery I have.... My problem is that it kind of inserts them randomly.. I would like to set it up to insert the most recently uploaded picture to the end of the gallery "row", any suggestions? Thanks

```
<?php

    $image_dir = 'uploads/images/';
    $per_column = 10;       

    if ($handle = opendir($image_dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
        {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') 
            {
                if(strstr($file,'.png'))
                {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
                if(strstr($file,'.jpg'))
                {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
                if(strstr($file,'.gif'))
                {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
                if(strstr($file,'.jpeg'))
                {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

    if(count($files))
    {
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $count++;
            echo '<li><img src="',$image_dir,$file,'" width="20" height="20" title="',$file,'"/></li>';
            if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no pictures yet...';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

    $image_dir = 'uploads/images/';
    $per_column = 10;       

    $validExt = array(
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    );

    if ($handle = opendir($image_dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
        {
            $ext = strtolower(substr($file, -3));
            if (isset($validExt[$ext])) 
            {
                $stats = stat($image_dir.$file);
                $files[$stats['mtime']] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

    $count = 0;
    krsort($files);

    $cnt = count($files);

    if($cnt)
    {
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $count++;
           echo '<li><img src="' . $image_dir . $file . '" width="20" height="20" title="' . substr($file, 0, -4) . '"/></li>'.chr(10);
            if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no pictures yet...';
    }
```

Comment: this is great, but it's the opposite way, the newest picture inserts into the front spot, i want it to go to the last spot, from left to right, your code inserted into the first spot and bumped the rest down..

Comment: Use ksort (krsort is reverse). The idea is to use the key of the array as the time uploaded. Then you sort the array by key.

Comment: another quick question for you... for the "title" attribute I have $file, but that gives me "example.png" when I hover... how can I make it drop the extension to just show "example"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your file format is, but try setting the filename to the current time using `time()` when uploading.

When you list your images, try using [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead of readdir.

Your code might then go as follows (untested):

```
$image_dir = 'uploads/images/';
$per_column = 10;       

$files = glob($image_dir . "*.jpg|png|gif|jpeg");

if(count($files))
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $count++;
        echo '<li><img src="',$image_dir,$file,'" width="20" height="20" title="',$file,'"/></li>';
        if($count % $per_column == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'no pictures yet...';
}
```

Coupling this with giving the uploaded file a filename of the current time, this should order your images by most recent.

The most important line here is `$files = glob($image_dir . "*.jpg|png|gif|jpeg");`. This will scan the directory for any file (`*`) ending in `.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif` or `.jpeg`. You don't need to worry about `.` and `..`; the expression filters that out.

Comment: very helpful, but I wanted to be able to have the image name as the image "title" attribute and it would be the hover name for each picture... if i give each a name of the current time it wouldn't work like that...

Comment: In that case, prepend the timestamp to the filename on upload, something like this: `12345678{|}My lovely picture.png`. The `{|}` is just an example of a separator you can use to split the timestamp off the string when you come to displaying it.